# Graduate application writing sample plagiarism

Tags: graduate-admissions

How likely the graduate admission committee will use plagiarism check software to check the writing sample submitted? I am just afraid something accidentally might pop up, like some sentence or something, which was not done on purpose.

Comment: If you didn't plagiarise, there is no reason to worry.

Comment: Sure, but I am just asking, you seem like a real professor haha

Comment: No, I am surely not a professor. You really flattered me. Similarity checker really does not tell you much about plagiarism. Assume that your writing sample was published in a pre-print server,  the similarity index will be really high. That does not mean that you plagiarised.

Comment: True, that's a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that very many people on an admissions committee would do that except in very rare cases in which something else triggers it.

It may be, however, that the job is getting a bit harder these days with AI based text generators. But in the US, at least, graduate admissions are based on a broad reading of an applicant's materials with many factors. I'd guess that a lot of writing samples get only a cursory reading in any case.

I also doubt that plagiarism checkers such as turnitin have a large enough comparison base to catch much in such a case. They are limited to what publishers permit them to index/archive.

And, as mentioned in a comment, if you haven't plagiarized, then a checker will only turn up a few phrases common to a field. And they will miss so much, via paraphrasing, that their use would have little real value.